# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Single user chat

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, chat

I'm having lot of troubles since I don't know how to start this thing.

I need something like a "chat" in my MVC web app, but the chat can't be shared amongst all of my visitors. What I mean is, I need just a page or a partial view or whatever you can imagine, where my site visitor writes something, lets say a question about a product that the site sells; then a little window pops up to the seller or whomever may be watching or taking care of the chat, and he/she will response to that message.

As an example, something like the facebook chat would be what I need, but instead of using google or facebook authentication, I would like to use my own authentication.
The main aspect to deploy is that when both ends of the communications are online, the communication should be "synchronous" or some like that; and when one end is offline, the communication should be "asynchronous", like a mail message.
By saying this, a "facebook like" chat, I mean all of its simple or common functions, to know: chat and message logging.

I'm really sorry about the messy writing, I don't know how to explain this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can easily embed a third party service for product assistance (if that's all you are looking for).

Comment: This looks interesting as well: http://www.geekbeing.com/2012/05/18/implement-live-web-chat-part-1

Comment: If by third party service you mean a plugin, if you have an example or a link to it, it would be great.

---

Thanks, I'll take a look to it.

Comment: I just googled "website chat" and found a bunch of plugins. Don't know which ones are good or not, but there are definitely a lot out there that seem free to try.

Comment: I actually wanted to know if there is a correct approach from where I can start, that link has some interesting information, but if I can take that thing to a "one on one" communication it will do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do this using **SignalR**... it was really neat and awesome working!

I'm sorry I don't give you further details, I don't remember from what link I took the code. I also had to do some minor tweaks in order to get a 1-to-1 functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is, but I would approach this by using jQuery for the front end and then storing the chat log in a database on the back end.  Make sure the chat log contains the users involved and the timestamp of each message.

Set a timeout event on the front end to check for new messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could start here...

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33396-basic-clientserver-chat-application-in-c%23/#/

I dont believe it includes persisting messages for later, but with a few modifications it could de done.

rename from .zip to .rar to open and include it in a solution.